# What is the meaning of the error getCode?

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

[image]

product code on /produkidbypulsa/ does not exist, should be /produkidbypulsa/1/
How do I fix it?

this is function getCode

```
function getCode() {

            var kode_produk = $('#pulsa').val();
//            pulsa.innerHTML = "";
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: '/produkbyidpulsa' + '/' + kode_produk,
                dataType: 'JSON',
                success: function (data) {
//                        pulsa.innerHTML +=
                    $('#kodeproduk').val(data.kode_produk)
                    $('#pulsa_code').val(data.pulsa_code)
                    $('#totalweb').val(data.harga_beli)
                    var kodeprod = data.kode_produk
                    $('#total').val(data.harga_jual)
                    $('#harga').html(data.harga_jual)
                    $.ajaxSetup({
                        headers: {
                            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                        }
                    })

                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'GET',
                        url: 'https://testprepaid.mobilepulsa.net/v1/legacy/index/pulsa' + kodeprod,
                        dataType: 'JSON',
                        processData: false,
                        contentType: 'application/json',
                        CrossDomain: true,
                        async: false,
                        success: function (data) {
                            $('#totalweb').val(data.harga_beli)
                        }
                    })
                }
            })
//            });
        }
```

and this is onclick for call getCode()

```
<div class="col-md-12" id="pulsa" name="pulsa" onclick="getCode()"><label for="harga"></label></div>
```

Comment: `$('#pulsa').val();` is undefined because your `div` with the id "pulsa" has no value. Where are you trying to get that value from?

Comment: get that value from button in another function `select.append("<button type='button' id='buttonpulsa' name='buttonpulsa' value='"+ data[i].kode_produk +"' data-total='"+ data[i].harga_jual +"'>"+data[i].nama_produk+"</button>");` @Nick

Comment: @SisiliaPutri, i think you append a button, can't get value from button.

Comment: how that the value can get value from the button? @Elango

Comment: @SisiliaPutri, You may get button value by like this $('#btn1').data('value'); use data-* attribute in your button